# Dynamic Edittext

Tags: android

I want take the value of `Edittext1` dynamically as soon as I press **ENTER** or **DONE** on the number pad that come up when I press `Edittext1.`

Also I want to take the value of `Edittext1` and multiply it and show the result on `Edittext2` and divide `Edittext1` and show the results on `Edittext3` and vise versa, dynamically.

I want to know what classes I should be using and how I should go about this.

Comment: Have you googled? Did you find anything like TextWatcher helpful?

Comment: use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
    }
});
```